# Figma - Difference color but "positive"

Tags: text, figma

I want to differentiate colors on a layer but the difference should be "positive", ie. orange and orange should be white rather than black. Here's a picture of what I mean:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

I created this by using two text layers but I would like to only use one. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not a figma user, but in other vector software such as Inkscape or Illustrator you can have different colours of text within the same text box. Basically you highlight some text and change the fill colour.  Perhaps you could look into that.

Comment: why do you want to use only one layer?

Comment: have you tried flattening and/ or outlining the text?

Comment: Hi - I don't know how you stumbled across this old post :D - I can't remember why I wanted just one layer. I think I wanted to easily change the text at any time without a big hassle. I think I did outline the text and I got it this way afaik - but it's been over a year. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A single text box can have multiple colors applied, including every single character having a different color. Just use the text tool to select the characters you want to change its color, and then pick a new fill.

The blue and black problem you’re getting is because the “Difference” blend mode just works the way you described (as “negative” of sorts). And either way, there’s no blend mode that’ll give you the result you want.